# "Existing Connection forcibly closed by remote host" on filling the data set using DataAdapter

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services, ado.net

I have been trying to query from oracle database using the following code,

```
public DataSet SelectCustomerDetails(string CustCode)
{

    String SQL = @"select cust.name,cust.code,cust.caddr from  cust
     where cust.code = '{0}'";

     OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
     connection.ConnectionString =System.Configuration. ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDB"].ConnectionString;
      connection.Open();

     SQL = string.Format(SQL, CustCode);
     OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, connection);

     DataSet CustDataSet = new DataSet();
     CustDataSet.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
     DA.Fill(CustDataSet);
     connection.Close();
}
```

I am sure that on this method call, I am getting the error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in a random fashion.. what could be reason for this issue..
[image]

Comment: There's nothing random about it.  You just haven't yet found the trigger.  What is the data type of `cust.cust_id`?  You're comparing it like a `String` but I would have assumed it to be a number, such as `Integer`.  There are lots of reasons for your error message...poor SQL, connection fail, out of memory...

Comment: @DonBoitnott there is no problem with the SQL when it is executed sperately using an oracle client.. i have edited the question, check now

Comment: Hello, have you ever found what was the problem?

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos we still have this in my old application developed in .net 3.5 and hosted in IIS7. we were actually trying to read directly from the third party application database. now that we are consuming their web service instead. otherwise that problem was never resolved.